# Javascript for loop is faster then AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, for-loop

so here is the problem:

I am looping an AJAX call for each post. The idea is to get a True or False from the ajax call. But I think the loop goes faster then the ajax call and I only get one result. That results also applies the other posts, so instead of getting a false for the other post, I get a true. Is there a way where the loop can wait until the ajax call is done?

```
function changMonth(month, active, url){
$('#eventTimeline').empty();

$('#month1, #month2, #month3, #month4, #month5, #month6, #month7, #month8, #month9, #month10, #month11, #month12').removeAttr('class');

$(active).attr('class', 'active');

base_url = $('#base_register').val();
user_id = $('#user_id').val();

$.post(url, {'month': month} , function(data){

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var splitDateString = new String(data[i].event_date);
        var splitDateArray = splitDateString.split('-');

        $.post(base_url + '/searchFilter/getRegisteredParents', {'event_id' : data[i].event_id}, function(data2){

            checkboolean = data2.check;
            ajaxFinnish = true;

        }, "json");

        if(ajaxFinnish == true)
        {

        $('#eventTimeline').append(

            '<div class="post' + i + '">' +
            '<h3>' + data[i].event_name + '</h3>' +
            '<div class="eventImage"><img width="113px" height="113px" src="' + data[i].event_photo + '" alt="&nbsp;" /></div>' +
            '<div class="eventText">' + data[i].event_details + '</div>' +
            '<div class="klas"><span>' + splitDateArray[2] + ' ' + maandArr[splitDateArray[1]] + '</span>' + data[i].group + '</div>' +
            '</div>'

        );

        $(".post" + i).css({'width': '605px', 'background-color': '#FFFFFF', 'border-bottom': 'solid 1px #4c585e', 'margin': '10px 5px 5px 5px', 'overflow': 'hidden' });


            if(checkboolean == "true")
            {
                //console.log('TRUE');
                $(".post" + i).append('<a href="#" class="eventMore">Uitschrijven</a>');
            }
            else
            {
                //console.log('False');
                $(".post" + i).append('<a href="#" class="eventMore">Inschrijven</a>');
            }
            ajaxFinnish = false;
        }


        console.log(checkboolean);
    }

}, "json");}
```

Comment: HOLY CRAP! **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML == **AJAX**. You just earned the repeater badge for asking an old 10000 asked question again. We can close this question as a duplicate of one of [those questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=return+from+ajax+callback) ARGGG!

Answer (score 1):

Without looking in detail at your code, I can already tell you by your description that the reason this is happening is because of the A in AJAX: Asynchronous.

Your AJAX call makes a call to your server, and while it's doing that, the rest of your code continues running. Because of this, your JS will almost always finish before your AJAX call. What you need to do is implement callbacks in your [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) functions. Using callbacks is the only reliable way to ensure that your code runs in the order you want it to:

```
function myCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
}

function myAjaxCall(myUrl, myData) {
    $.ajax(myUrl, {data: myData }).done(myCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a for loop wait.  The best thing to do in this scenario would be to use setTimeout to call the initial ajax, and for each subsequent call, you would make the same setTimeout call.

Comment: no effing way. race conditions like whoa. you need to use callbacks